# Error in facebook login "attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope"

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have a Facebook app, and the first thing happens is to ask the user to login.
I am using the

```
 <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" scope="read_stream,offline_access,status_update,publish_stream,manage_pages,user_photos"></fb:login-button>
```

Then what happens is that I get this error in Firebug:

```
 all.js (line 22)
 attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
 [Break On This Error] FB.provide('',{ui:function(f,b){f=FB.c...onent(FB.UIServer._resultToken));}})
```

I am using Firefox 4, and this error does not happen always. Only some times. 
Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance